# How to delete "explorer.exe" in batch?

Tags: batch

So, I was working on a GUI written in Batch only, for a project at school.
now that I coded the GUI, it needs to be replaced with the "explorer.exe" located in "C:\Windows" and NO. I am not talking about "iexplorer.exe". nowhere is my question: How do I delete (I have a backup) the explorer.exe in batch code only? (with admin permissions). just "taskkill /f /im explorer.exe" and "del C:\Windows\explorer.exe /f" dosen't work, because it just returns "Access Denied". anyone a suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Which the Windows version? Check it out with the cmd **winver**.

Comment: Why does it need to replace Explorer.exe on disk? What are you trying to achieve by doing it? Are you trying to replace the "Shell" as referenced here: 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` ?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 Build 1909, and no from a `.reg` file it dosen`t work, or replacing it using batch only isn't an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must to change ownership and permissions of explore.exe file to do that one succesfull.

Create a file called **script.bat** somewhere, in that case I created in **C:\script.bat** with the following content:

```
echo off
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
takeown /a /f C:\Windows\explorer.exe
icacls C:\Windows\explorer.exe /grant administrators:f
del C:\Windows\explorer.exe
```

Run *Task Scheduler* by cmd **taskschd.msc /s**

Go to **Create Task ...**

Enter *Name:* field with **ScriptTask**

Left click on **Run whether user is logged on or not**

Check **Do not store password. The Task will only have access to local computer resources.**

Check **Run with highest privileges**

Go to *Triggers* tab

Left click on **New...**

Change *Begin the task* to **At startup**

Go to *Actions* tab

Left click on **New...**

Enter *Program/script:* field with **C:\script.bat**

Left click on **OK**

Left click on **OK** again

Then, restart your machine by cmd **shutdown /t 0 /r**

The *script* will delete the *explorer.exe* file sucessfully during the system startup.

References:

- [How to Delete Files Protected by TrustedInstaller in Windows 10 - QUICK AND EASY!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuuAt9dmUrM)
- [icacls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)
- [takeown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/takeown)
- [How to Write a Batch Script on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/263177/how-to-write-a-batch-script-on-windows/)